# Capistrano Bundler: How to make it verbose?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

Is it possible to let `Capistrano` print the output of bundler, when running the bundle command?

On the local machine it usually prints "using rails 4.2.1" etc. and I would love to have the same when deploying to my live server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because Capistrano uses Bundler with the options `--deployment --quiet` by default. So the `--quiet` suppresses the desired output.

Add the following line to the production configuration of Capistrano:

```
set :bundle_flags, '--deployment'
```

You can find out more about [Capistranos Bundler plugin from its repository](https://github.com/capistrano/bundler/).